How to register an Asset Bundle in Craft CMS 3.x to style a Twig template?
I'm trying to create and register an Asset Bundle in Craft CMS 3.x to include a custom CSS file for styling a Twig template. I've followed the official documentation provided by Craft CMS: Asset Bundles | Craft CMS Documentation | 3.x, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to work as expected.
What I have done so far:
1. Created the Asset Bundle: I created an 'AssetBundle' class within my custom mudule like this:
<?php
namespace modules\logviewer\src;

use craft\web\AssetBundle;
use craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset;

class LogviewerAssetBundle extends AssetBundle
{
    public function init()
    {
        // define the path that your publishable resources live
        $this->sourcePath = '@modules/logviewer/src/resources';

        // define the dependencies
        $this->depends = [
            CpAsset::class,
        ];

        // define the relative path to CSS files that should be registered with the page
        // when this asset bundle is registered
        $this->css = [
            'styles.css',
        ];

        parent::init();
    }
}

2. Registered the Asset Bundle in the controller: I registered the Asset Bundle in my Controller before rendering the template like this: $this->view->registerAssetBundle(LogviewerAssetBundle::class);
The Problem:
Despite following the steps in the documentation, the CSS file is not being included in my rendered Twig template. I've checked the page source in my browser, but the <link> tag for the asset is missing.
What I have tried:

Double-checked the paths in the sourcePath of the Asset Bundle.
Cleared the cache in Craft CMS to ensure there were no old references.
Inspected the browser console for any errors related to missing assets, but found nothing unusual.
Verified that the controller action is being executed properly.

Question:
What am I missing or doing wrong in the process of registering and using an Asset Bundle in Craft CMS 3.x? How can I properly include my CSS file so that it is available in my Twig template?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide the relevant code for the twig template as well

@DarkBee Thank you for your feedback. I understand the request for the Twig template code to ensure everything is set up correctly. But I haven't made any specific changes in the Twig template to register the Asset Bundle, as the Craft Documentation suggests that asset bundles can be registered either in the Template or in the Controller. I opted to register the Asset Bundle through the Controller. If you think there's something missing or if there are other suggestions on what might be causing the issue, please let me know. Many thanks in advance :)
